# Is there a way to remove domain in the push notification from Notification API

Tags: reactjs, notifications

Hey I am currently using a package react-web-notification on my React Web
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-web-notification

I am trying to remove the domain inside the notification, but couldn't find a way to do that.

Currently both Chrome and FireFox shows the domain name in bold. I have attached a image below. Just trying to get rid of localhost.a2z.com:3000

If there is no way to get rid of it, is there a way not to bold it?

[image]

Comment: The documentation for `react-web-notification` doesn't have anything about changing the styling of the notification?

Comment: No, I don't think so, it mentions about options here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/Notification

Comment: Just didn't see anything that changes the domain.